# node.js - repeatedly updating webpage from mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, repeat

I am trying to create a node.js app to automatically update a webpage every few seconds with new data from a mysql database. I have followed the information on this site: http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/

The code on this site does indeed work, but upon further testing it keeps running the "handler" function and therefore executing the readFile function for each row of the database processed.

I am in the process of learning node.js, but cannot understand why the handler function keeps getting called. I would only like it to get called once per connection. Constantly reading the index.html file like this seems very ineffecient.

The reason that I know the handler function keeps getting called is that I placed a `console.log("Hello");` statement in the handler function and it keeps outputting that line to the console.

Comment: The handler function should only get called when you make a request to the web server (ie. from your browser). readFile() is simply loading the HTML file to return to the user, not looking up database records. What results are you getting that indicates the handler function is running over and over?

Comment: I placed a console.log("Hello"); statement in the handler function, and it keeps printing that line out to the console.

Comment: Also, can someone let me know why this question was downvoted? It is my very first post on stackoverflow, so am not completely familiar with the etiquette yet. I have been trying to figure this out on my own for the past few days and have done a lot of researching and experimenting with code, but still cannot figure this out. I can see someone getting downvoted by being lazy and not doing their due research, but that is not the case here. Also, if I have been unclear in any way, why not ask for clarification so that I can improve it. Downvoting without explanation does not help me improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you provide the image URLs that the client.html is looking for? Here's what I think is happening:

The client connects to your server via Socket.IO and retrieves the user information (user_name, user_description, and user_img). The client then immediately tries to load an image using the user_img URL. The author's server code however, doesn't appear to support serving these pictures. Instead it just returns the same client.html file for every request. This would be why it appears to be calling handler over and over again - it's trying to load a picture for every user.

I would recommend using the **express module** in node to serve static files instead of trying to do it by hand. Your code would look something like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.use(app.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

That essentially says to serve any static files they request from the public folder. In that folder you will put client.html as well as the user photos.

Comment: Thank you! I had not even considered that it was the image URLs causing that. :)